# Should I be concerned that Configuration Utility says my devices have “untrusted” certificates?

Tags: ios, certificate, configuration-files

In iPhone Configuration Utility, under the Summary pane for all of my iOS devices, I see warning in the Certificate panel that says "This certificate was signed by an untrusted issuer".

Should I be concerned about this? Why would this be the case? Is there any way this could have been caused by using Xcode? Is there a way to assign a trusted certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably that you haven't installed certificate root issuers certificate and that's why you are receiving that error message. You shouldn't be worried about it.

Comment: Any idea where I could acquire the missing certificate, or why Apple wouldn't have included the necessary ones (given that it's running on their own OS)?